# Having trouble installing nvidia drivers on ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation

I am new to Linux. I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop and having been trying to install the nvidia drivers. At first I just tried downloading the install from the NVIDIA website, I would run it and let it do the installing. But at the end it would always crash saying it cant open the file I believe. Then I tried installing them the following method.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-415
```

This seemed to work better but at the end it would tell me that since my laptop is in UEFI Mode it would need me to setup a password that would be asked from me upon booting. Problem is I had no where to input the password. At the bottom of the terminal there was an <kbd>OK</kbd> "button" but it would not work and neither would enter.

Any advice?

Edit : I also tried choosing a different mode than UEFI from the bios but UEFI was the only option.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS?